# Using Contains() in a Where LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, list, contains

I'm using this piece of code to get a desired list of rows from a table:

```
_userObjectSet = EntityFrameWorkContext.CreateObjectSet<User>();
List<int> selectedUserIDs = Method(); //Returns a specific set of int user IDs...
var results = _userObjectSet.Where(c => selectedUserIDs.Contains(c.ID)).ToList();
```

This does work as 'results' will only contain records whose ID field matches an element in the selectedUserIDs list.

The problem is that, if I look at Windows Task Manager, LINQ seems to load ALL of the table's row THEN filter them out. There is a huge number of rows in this table, and pretty soon the process weights over 1GB, which I don't really like.

I can also tell that it's doing this because of the time it takes to complete.

Is there any way to tell LINQ to generate a query that would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID IN (34,55,66,77, etc.)
```

which would only return the exact rows I'm looking for and use less memory ?

Thanks!

Comment: If this is linq-to-sql that is what should be happening. Have you tried logging the generated SQL by setting the `Log` property of your data context to a debug window? How many ids does `selectedUserIDs` contain?

Comment: This is just a thought (since this is what NHibernate expects), but have you tried `_userObjecSet.Where(c => selectedUserIDs.Any(y => y == c.ID)).ToList();` or similar? (NOTE: May not be 100% correct)

Comment: The table contains 800,000+ rows, the List contains only 3000 or so. I can run a profiler for sure.

Comment: What type is `_userObjectSet` declared as, and how does it get set?

Comment: @Francis a SQL `In` clause with 3000 items is a...lot.  It's possible that the query provider can only create the `In` clause when the list is less than some certain number of items.  Ideally instead of having a list in code the ID values will be in another table in the database and you would do a `Join`.  It may even be worth inserting them into a temp table and then doing a `Join` even if the IDs are temporary.

Comment: As well as a profiler see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx. This lets you log to the debug window.

Comment: it is an ObjectSet created from an Entity Framework Context. I will update my question.

Comment: @Servy If you made that an answer I would upvote it. Great suggestion.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Well, the first part is a guess, which is why it's a comment.  The fix is almost certainly a good idea, but the reason it's not working may be something entirely different.  I also have no idea how one might use a temp table in EF.

Comment: If you use this in ASP.NET MVC, [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) is a great tool to see the actual generated SQL.

Comment: Through SQL Profiler, I was able to confirm LINQ builds a WHERE-less query, then filters out...

Comment: A general question on this topic, it's my understanding that the cost of a Where operation is incurred when it's enumerated.  So what would happen if ToList() was removed?  Would that make any difference?

Comment: @Forty-Two That would just mean the work wouldn't happen until later, when you enumerated it.  The main point here is that this query can't be converted by the query provider into SQL, so it's being evaluated through LINQ to Objects.  Deferring execution for a while won't change that.

Comment: @Francis Is the ID `List` generated from another database query?  Is it possible to get that data as an `IQueryable<int>` representing some other query as opposed to a list of items?

Comment: @Servy, yes. The IDs are in fact coming from a different database than the _userObjectSet is tied to.

Comment: Did you try with the join..

Comment: Tried what Servy proposed, using IQueryable<> and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try join.. I think u can find a difference...

```
List<int> selectedUserIDs = Method(); //Returns a specific set of int user IDs...
var results = (from u in _userObjectSet 
               join id in selectedUserIDs on u.Id equals id
               select u);
```

Answer (score -1):

You're going to need something like [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) for this.Specifically, have a look at the PredicateBuilder that comes with the kit, as I think you need that to solve your problem.

Comment: Not really sure if this will work, given the size of the `List` (3000 items).

Comment: Although a useful link, I'm not sure how helpful this answer is given that there is nothing obvious in there that will actually solve this issue.

Comment: I didn't notice the comment about 3000 items when I started typing (which is a bit slow on a tablet)..